# Twitch API - can't get auth token using PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, json, twitch

Hello stackoverflow members. 
I'm not a person who likes to ask for a help but in this case it's IMO the only way to solve my problem. Google didn't help me much.

So. My problem:
I want to get some data using Twitch API. Sounds easy? I wish it was. Below I'm posting my actual code (it's small but it was modified various of times and now it look like...):

```
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CORRECT_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost/php/twitch.php&scope=user_read'), true);
print_r($user); // returns nothing

$token = $user['access_token'];
print_r($token); // same as above

$ch = curl_init();

// some stupid curls
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/followed'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Authorization: OAuth '.$token ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$retval = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$result = json_decode($retval, true);
```

It returns... Nothing. So I used ready solution from discussions.twitch. (I wish I could write the name of the author of this code but I'm too tired to search it again. Either way thanks!):

```
$ch = curl_init("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$fields = array(
    'client_id' => 'blablabla_correct',
    'client_secret' => 'blablabla_also_correct',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/php/twitch.php',
    'code' => $_GET['code']
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($data, true);
//var_dump($response);
$access_token = $response["access_token"];
echo $access_token;

function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $returnobj = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $returnobj;
}

$testobj = json_decode(get_data("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/user?oauth_token=".$access_token."&client_id=".$fields['client_id']));
echo "<br>Data: ";

print_r($testobj);
```

This code above is a bit better. Only a bit. It returns **Error 401**. Why? Because it can't get *auth token*. Well, it's something but not what I wanted to get. What should I do now? Maybe it's fault of localhost address?

FAQ(?):
Yes, I'm using correct data from my Twitch application settings page.
Yes, I'm confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making two calls to the Twitch API, and you need to debug them independently.

For now, just skip the second call.  Focus on the one where you grab your access token.

Try this:

```
// to start, just use the code you've already got:
$ch = curl_init("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$fields = array(
    'client_id' => 'blablabla_correct',
    'client_secret' => 'blablabla_also_correct',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/php/twitch.php',
    'code' => $_GET['code']
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

// Now, here we believe the first error comes into play, so let's check it out
print_r($data); // confirm that this is not what we want
$info = curl_getinfo($ch); // let's get some details about that last request
// print it out and see what we get
echo '<pre>';
print_r($info);
echo '</pre>';
```

... that should give you a starting point to figure out what's going on.  If you see an auth token, then you're not accessing it in the right way.  If you don't, the info will give you some information about why.

I don't know what `redirect_uri` is (can you link to docs that explain it?) so I can't know if the localhost reference is a problem there.

Comment: If you can provide more information after this first debugging step, then we can try to take another step.

Comment: redirect_uri is from API documentation and it should be in this request. Your code works fine and somehow it's the solution for my issue. Thank You.