# Twitch API - asked for auth token return nothing

Tags: php, json, api, curl, twitch

I have similar question to this one: [Twitch API - can't get auth token using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746548/twitch-api-cant-get-auth-token-using-php/23747082#23747082?newreg=cafbfae0039a407e80ff652582ce7177) but cannot write a comment.

Tried the code:

```
    $ch = curl_init("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$fields = array(
    'client_id' => 'blablabla_correct',
    'client_secret' => 'blablabla_also_correct',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/php/twitch.php',
    'code' => $_GET['code']
);


 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
print $data;
```

But it prints nothing. So i tried to debug request using the code from #2:

```
// to start, just use the code you've already got:
$ch = curl_init("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$fields = array(
    'client_id' => 'blablabla_correct',
    'client_secret' => 'blablabla_also_correct',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/php/twitch.php',
    'code' => $_GET['code']
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

// Now, here we believe the first error comes into play, so let's check it out
print_r($data); // confirm that this is not what we want
$info = curl_getinfo($ch); // let's get some details about that last request
// print it out and see what we get
echo '<pre>';
print_r($info);
echo '</pre>';
```

And I get following Array. I have no idea what to do next. The API docs are here: https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/authentication.md#auth-code

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.203
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.203
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_ip] => 192.16.71.172
    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => 192.168.1.100
    [local_port] => 51603
    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

i can be wrong but as other login providers, i could imagine that twitch also not allows `redirect urls` to non existing domains like `localhost`.

if you want localhost return urls i can prefer this service, where you can point your redirect url to a wildcard server and the request gets redirect to your localhost.

http://xip.io

> xip.io is a magic domain name that provides wildcard DNS for any IP
>   address. Say your LAN IP address is 10.0.0.1. Using xip.io,
>
> ```
>      10.0.0.1.xip.io            resolves to   10.0.0.1
>      www.10.0.0.1.xip.io        resolves to   10.0.0.1    
>      mysite.10.0.0.1.xip.io     resolves to   10.0.0.1  
>      foo.bar.10.0.0.1.xip.io    resolves to   10.0.0.1
> ```

Comment: Still nothing, but thanks for showing the xip.io site, it can be useful in the future :) btw. from Twitch App "This must exactly match the redirect_uri parameter passed to the authorization endpoint. When testing locally, you can set this to http://localhost. "

Comment: Tried on live site - nothing.